# Is it possible to get the iteration number of a lambda map?

Tags: python

I have this simple map:

```
list( map(lambda p: mappingFunction(p,index?), data )
```

I'd like, on my mapping function, to be able to access the index, so to have 0,1,2,3,... and track the iteration number.
Is that possible?

Comment: A list comprehension will do what you want I think `[mappingFunction(p, i) for i, p in enumerate(data)]`

Comment: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

Comment: can you please write the full code?

Comment: tomjn already provided the full code. That's literally it in their comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `map` on your iterable, call it on an enumerate of your iterable. Enumerate returns tuples of index-value pairs:

```py
[(0, data[0]), (1, data[1]), (2, data[2]), ...]
```

```py
def f(index, value):
    pass # stuff...

map(f, enumerate(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` to produce an array of indexes with the same length as `data` and pass it to `map`.

```py
data = [10, 20, 30, 40]
mappingFunction = lambda x, y: (x, y)

res = list(map(lambda index, p: mappingFunction(index, p), range(len(data)), data))
print(res)  # [(0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 30), (3, 40)]
```